# With Azure Ls_v2 is it possible to backup/snapshot the NVME disk?

Tags: backup, azure

The Ls_v2 series of databases promise high IOPS and troughput for a low price. The block device that is this fast is a HyperV-NVME directly accessed local hardware drive.

The azure disaster recovery and backup services that are available in the portal do not seem to offer a way to backup data on the NVME disks.

Is there an easy way to backup snapshots of this data? Or is this not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these disks are directly attached from the hardware they are no table to be snap-shotted or backed up directly.

The only solution that would really work would be to install the Azure Backup Agent on the machine, and then backup the files directly.